# IMAPI2 How to burn an already created iso

Tags: c#, iso, imapi

I have read [hackchina](http://www.hackchina.com/en/r/23159/MainForm.cs__html) and [codeproject](http://www.hackchina.com/en/r/23159/MainForm.cs__html) examples but it seems I can not figure out how to burn an existing .iso file. The examples above show ways of making an .iso from a folder and then burning it. I want to be able to directly burn an iso file.

Here is some code:

```
IDiscRecorder2 discRecorder = new MsftDiscRecorder2();
string Burner = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();

foreach (DrvProperties prop in drv_props)
{
  if (prop.letter.Contains(Burner)) // letter contains the drive's Letter (E:, G: etc.)
  {
    discRecorder.InitializeDiscRecorder(prop.ID); // ID contains drive's uniqueID
  }

}

IDiscFormat2Data discFormatData = new MsftDiscFormat2Data();
discFormatData.Recorder = discRecorder;

IMAPI_MEDIA_PHYSICAL_TYPE mediaType = discFormatData.CurrentPhysicalMediaType;
......
......
```

Could someone please help me get further? Lets say I have example.iso. What should I do now? I don't understand. (I got using IMAPI2.interop in my code from CodeProject example).

Thanks a lot

Comment: Please someone how can i add a .iso file in a MsftFileSystemImage object what can i do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well i finally figured it out firstly you need to include the following name spaces:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes;
```

In order to be able to use IStream.

Then you need to import SHCreateStreamOnFIle from shlwapi.dll to open a "read stream" to that iso:

```
private const uint STGM_SHARE_DENY_WRITE = 0x00000020;
    private const uint STGM_SHARE_DENY_NONE = 0x00000040;
    private const uint STGM_READ = 0x00000000;
    private const uint STGM_WRITE = 0x00000001;
    private const uint STGM_READWRITE = 0x00000002;

     [DllImport("shlwapi.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, ExactSpelling = true,    PreserveSig = false, EntryPoint = "SHCreateStreamOnFileW")]
    static extern void SHCreateStreamOnFile(string fileName, uint mode, ref IStream stream);

IStream stream = null;
SHCreateStreamOnFile(path2iso, STGM_READ | STGM_SHARE_DENY_WRITE, ref stream);
```

and finally supply i to the discFormatData.Write() method.

```
discFormatData.Write(stream);
```

I hope it helps someone. Take care